# Flutter Bloc Auth wont listen ( stuck at onGenerateRoute )

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

iam currently learning on bloc , i follow this code `https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_login`
but while iam running ,but i got stuck at splashscreen and cant going through the dashboard / loginpage

iam using paste bin because i got warning `It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`

MyMain

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  NavigatorState get _navigator => _navigatorKey.currentState!;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _authenticationRepository = AuthRepository();
    return RepositoryProvider.value(
      value: _authenticationRepository,
      child: BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => AuthBloc(authRepository: _authenticationRepository),
          child: MaterialApp(
            navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
            builder: (context, child) {
              return BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                listener: (context, state) {
                  switch (state.status) {
                    case AuthStatus.authenticated:
                      _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                        DashBoard.route(),
                        (route) => false,
                      );
                      break;
                    case AuthStatus.unauthenticated:
                      _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                        LoginPage.route(),
                        (route) => false,
                      );
                      break;
                    default:
                      _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                        LoginPage.route(),
                        (route) => false,
                      );
                      break;
                  }
                },
                child: child,
              );
            },
            onGenerateRoute: (_) => SplashScreen.route(),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

MyAuthBloc

```
https://pastebin.com/BQnhDeFE
```

MyAuthState

```
https://pastebin.com/fmfnMwCV
```

MyAuthEvent

```
https://pastebin.com/tcEeqQsr
```

By Adding initstate on Splash Screen and calling autinital that's work

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthInitial());
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can notice in the [example](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_login/lib/authentication/bloc/authentication_bloc.dart) subscription on repository is present:

```
 _authenticationStatusSubscription = _authenticationRepository.status.listen(
      (status) => add(AuthenticationStatusChanged(status)),
    );
```

`AuthenticationRepository` triggers the fist `AuthenticationStatusChanged` event

Since you are starting with Bloc library i suggest you wrap your main with [BlocObserver](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc/example):

```
void main() {
  BlocOverrides.runZoned(
    () => runApp(const App()),
    blocObserver: AppBlocObserver(),
  );
}

/// Custom [BlocObserver] that observes all bloc and cubit state changes.
class AppBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase bloc, Change change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    if (bloc is Cubit) print(change);
  }

  @override
  void onTransition(Bloc bloc, Transition transition) {
    super.onTransition(bloc, transition);
    print(transition);
  }
}
```

It will ease up the learning process and verification if events correct events are there

Comment: i do wrap the myapp with blocobserver like this ```https://pastebin.com/3kgxxhDx``` i cut the code because cannot post to much code xD , so while iam not listen any stream to authentication how i access the initial state then ? or maybe i just need create initstate for calling this ``` context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthInitial())``` ?

Comment: You can do that or:

```BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => AuthBloc(authRepository: _authenticationRepository)..add(AuthenticationStatusChanged()),
```
Truth is since you are not listening on any stream to authenticate this looses sense .
Nothing stops you to just go directly to the login page instead of SplashScreen since you are not waiting for anything

Comment: or  ```BlocProvider(           create: (_) => AuthBloc(authRepository: _authenticationRepository)..add(AuthInitial())```